# Button placement in the footer of card layout?

Tags: buttons, material-design, cards

Should the button be placed on the bottom left corner or bottom right corner in the card layout?

I was referring to Google's material design I found out that action buttons are placed on the bottom left corner? Is there is any specific reason? Or it can be placed on the bottom right corner as well?

Link: https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#anatomy

Answer (score 1):

This applies to any form or page. The button is placed on the left because all items are left aligned on the card. If they were centre aligned, the button would be in the centre as well.

The reason why a form submit button is placed at the bottom-right even though the form elements may be left-aligned is to make the button stand out that this button applies to the entire form and not to some step in the middle of the page. To keep the button on the right would mean this is the end of the form or section.

Answer (score 0):

Good question which I asked myself in a recent project too. Here are my thoughts:

If I didn't know these guidelines i would place the action buttons on the right (at least in an environment where reading goes from left to right). The reason is that user tend to scann a card from top left to bottom right.

I do not now the reason why google places the buttons on the right.But if using material design patterns is a condition, i would go with the buttons on the left. The reason is, that be following this rules, every app in material design would work the same way and users will be used to that.

This are only my thought and not the answer to your question on the 'why' but this can only be answered by google.